# How to hide the dead and soft zone,height and width from play mode scree

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, cinemachine

I used the Cinemachine for camera follow, but I want to hide the dead and soft zone colours from the screen and not have it show those colours during runtime.

Comment: They don’t show normally. Unless you have done something to turn some gizmos on in the play screen

Comment: @BugFinder yes, I actually have. I'm using the linerenderer you see, and it's a very important part for me in my work. Is there a way I can turn of the gizmos for the Cinemachine only?

Comment: Hi @BugFinder, thank you so much for replying. I went to bed, woke up this morning, opened my project and the colours are gone. Thank you once again for your help 

Answer (score 1):

You need to uncheck **Game Window Guides** flag in the Cinemachine Virtual Camera component. More information about **Game Window Guides**   [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.3/manual/CinemachineVirtualCamera.html)

[image: Refer to this picture]